# How to parse out punctuation and replace with html tags in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, string-parsing

I was wondering if there is a way to take a string like

```
$string = "Look at *me* because I am bold";
```

and replace the asterisks with tags so the string would be

```
echo $string; //"Look at <bold>me</bold> because I am bold"
```

Comment: If this is a small, limited-use test or personal project, inhan's solution is probably fine. If you're looking to do more replacements and be able to handle more complex transformations and want to be absolutely sure you aren't messing anything up (especially if you're dealing with user input), you may want to look into a `Markdown` library for PHP. I haven't used it, but [this](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) seems as good as any, if Google rankings are to be believed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$string = preg_replace('~\*(.*?)\*~','<bold>$1</bold>',$string);`

**Edit:** Appended the semicolon I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Don't roll your own, you'll quickly end up with a bunch of special cases and loads of trouble.  Just get yourself a proper Markdown library and move onto something more important.